# Understanding Powershell variable scope

Tags: powershell, scope

Im trying to understand how variables retain values and the scope.  To that end I created two simple scripts.

The low level script looks like this

```
param(
    $anumber=0
)

function PrintNumber
{
    Write-Host "Number is $anumber"
    $anumber++
    Write-Host "Number is now $anumber"
}
```

The top level script looks like this

```
$scriptPath=(Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath)+"\" + "calledscript.ps1"
#dot source the called script
. $scriptPath 22

for($i=0;$i -lt 10;$i++)
{
    PrintNumber
}
```

the main script 'dot sources' the called script once, at the start and passes in a value , "22".  I then call the PrintNumber function 10 times from within the top level script.  I thought the outputs would look like:

Number is 22
Number is now 23

Number is 23
Number is now 24

Number is 24
Number is now 25

but instead the number is always 22 when the function is called, (output as below).  Why is this number resetting to 22 each time, even though I've only pulled in the dot source script once and init'ed the number to 22 there?

Number is 22
Number is now 23

Number is 22
Number is now 23

Number is 22
Number is now 23

Thanks

(please ignore any typos)

Comment: What happens if you change its definition to `$global:anumber`?

Comment: I changed the reference(not the declaration) from $anumber++ to $global:anumber++ and it then increments as I expected.  Not entirely sure why really!!

Comment: Definitely a scoping issue. I don't know a lot in depth but there are `local`, `script` and `global` variables in PowerShell. Makes sense that since you're sourcing the variable from a different script, the default scope is `script` and the incremented value doesn't persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of variable inheritance. Technet explains it like this.

```
A child scope does not inherit the variables, aliases, and functions from
the parent scope. Unless an item is private, the child scope can view the
items in the parent scope. And, it can change the items by explicitly 
specifying the parent scope, but the items are not part of the child scope.
```

Since the script is dot-sourced it creates a variable that is local to the session. When the function accesses a variable with the same name it can read the variable from the parent scope, but then it creates a local copy which is then incremented and subsequently destroyed.

Comment: Thanks @JonC, but what variable is the function reading from the parent scope?  I only have the variable in the called script, not the parent.

Comment: Another question is how would one explicitly specify the parent scope?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx covers the basics of scopes. The short answer is using modifiers like $global:anumber or $script:anumber. You can also use relative modifiers with cmdlets like `get-variable -name anumber -scope 0` where 0 is the current scope and 1 is the immediate parent, 2 the next parent and so forth.

Comment: Thanks Jonc, I have read through that. Just need to inwardly digest now.